# How to position VueJS components

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, tailwind-css, v-slot

I have a design brief which requires me to move the red component (*on the right*) to the red frame/shell(*on the left*).

The two categories/sections comes from a REST-API, with their children in side like that.

**[ What i've tried ]**

I tried positioning the red component absolute, but the problem was that if the content of the component above it grow. the two components are going to overlap.

> I couldn't find exactly where to position it. (in terms on Y axis)

**[ What i would like ]**

I was hoping that maybe i can use `v-slot` to create a shell/frame on the left, then i template the component on the right and yield it to the shell/frame on the left side.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, that's what you need :
// sorry for plain css, I just don't know how insert scss in stackoverflow snippet box

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button')
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')

btn.onclick = () => grid.classList.toggle('replaced')
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  column-gap: 20px;
  row-gap: 20px;
}

div {
  background: black;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  order: 10;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  order: 20;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  order: 30;
}

div:nth-child(4) {
  order: 40;
  background: red;
}

.replaced div:nth-child(4) {
  order: 11;
}
```

```html
<main class="grid replaced">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</main>


<button>toggle</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately you missed one thing. I do not want to remove the right section. i only want to move the red element. and leave others just the way they are.

Comment: Look at that picture again, the red filled square has to move to the red frame (red bordered square). I really appreciate your effort though.

Comment: @chawila in one picture you have 4 rectangles, in the other 2, what should happen to the remaining ones when you move the square?

Comment: Nothing should happen to the remain three on the right.. they should remain exactly were they are. NB:  the red frame on the left is just a placeholder.